# writing to a file from a class member function in c++

Tags: class, ostream, member-functions

```
void Tree::printTree(Node* cur){
if(cur->left){
    printTree(cur->left);
}
outFile << cur->getValue();
if(cur->right){
    printTree(cur->right);
}
```

}

I need to write to a file from a member fuction of a class. However, the output stream object is declared in my main function and I get an error saying that outFile has not been declared in this scope. I tried passing an ostream object as a parameter but haven't had any luck with that. Any suggestions?

My attempt at passing an ostream object as a parameter:

```
void Tree::printTree(Node* cur, ostream &output){
if(cur->left){
    printTree(cur->left, &output);
}
output << cur->getValue();
if(cur->right){
    printTree(cur->right, &output);
}
```

}

I get an error saying that ostream has not been declared, even when I include

EDIT: Fixed, I had include iostream in my .cpp but not my .h.

Comment: "I tried passing an ostream object as a parameter" --- show your best attempt, together with compiler errors/warnings you are having.

Comment: `std::ostream`?

Comment: I am using namespace std, that should cover it right?

Comment: You're either not including it or not `using namespace` it.

Comment: What happens when you try `std::ostream`?